# Given cosets $aH = bH$, it is not necessarily true that $Ha = Hb$. Ok but why?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let

- $H$ be a subgroup of $G$;
- $a$ and $b$ belong to $G$

Then $aH = bH$ does not always imply $Ha = Hb$, as shown by a counter example of the symmetric group $3$.

I can see that this is indeed a counter example. But can anyone tell me intuitively / conceptually why it is the case? (Or am I meant to just try out a few common groups to look for contradictions, after failing to prove that it is otherwise?)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$aH=bH$ is equivalent to $b^{-1}a \in H$, and $Ha = Hb$ is equivalent to $ab^{-1} \in H$. So if we let $c = b^{-1}a$, we have $ab^{-1} = bcb^{-1}$.

Thus it's enough to find a group $G$, a subgroup $H$, and two elements $b$ and $c$ such that $c \in H$ and $bcb^{-1} \not\in H$. (Then take $a = bc$.) But if $H$ is an example of this, then the subgroup of $G$ generated by $c$ will also be an example of it, so it's enough that $bcb^{-1}$ is not a power of $c$.

Here is an example of that. Let $G$ be the group of isometries of the plane. Take $c$ to be a reflection with respect to some line $L$ in the plane. Then the subgroup generated by $c$ is $\{e,c\}$. If $b$ is any isometry, then $bcb^{-1}$ is the reflection with respect to the line $b(L)$. So it's enough to pick $b$ so that $b(L) \ne L$.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that multiplication on the left is distinct from multiplication on the right (that is, the fact that the maps $x\mapsto ax$ and $x\mapsto xa$ are distinct) isn't enough?

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you.